# SQLAlchemy Query and_/or_ Issue

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a query that I'm trying to build.  The query seems to work in parts, both separate parts of the query return the correct number of elements.  However, the combined query returns an empty result set, which is incorrect.

Note: I know the and_'s are not needed for Query 1 and 2, but I wanted to make sure that and_ was working as I expected it to.

**Query 1**:

- SQLAlchemy Query

  ```
  session.query(Lobby).filter(
      and_(
          Lobby.id == spectator_table.c.lobby_id,
          spectator_table.c.player_id == player.steamid
      )
  ).all()
  ```
- Generated SQL

  ```
  SELECT lobby.id AS lobby_id, lobby.name AS lobby_name, lobby.owner_id AS lobby_owner_id
  FROM lobby, spectator
  WHERE lobby.id = spectator.lobby_id AND spectator.player_id = ?
  ```

**Query 2**:

- SQLAlchemy Query

  ```
  session.query(Lobby).filter(
      and_(
          Lobby.id == Team.lobby_id,
          LobbyPlayer.team_id == Team.id,
          LobbyPlayer.player_id == player.steamid
      )
  ).all()
  ```
- Generated SQL

  ```
  SELECT lobby.id AS lobby_id, lobby.name AS lobby_name, lobby.owner_id AS lobby_owner_id
  FROM lobby, team, lobby_player
  WHERE lobby.id = team.lobby_id AND lobby_player.team_id = team.id AND lobby_player.player_id = ?
  ```

**Combined Query**:

- SQLAlchemy Query

  ```
  session.query(Lobby).filter(
      or_(
          and_(
              Lobby.id == Team.lobby_id,
              LobbyPlayer.team_id == Team.id,
              LobbyPlayer.player_id == player.steamid
          ), and_(
              Lobby.id == spectator_table.c.lobby_id,
              spectator_table.c.player_id == player.steamid
          )
      )
  ).all()
  ```
- Generated SQL

  ```
  SELECT lobby.id AS lobby_id, lobby.name AS lobby_name, lobby.owner_id AS lobby_owner_id
  FROM lobby, team, lobby_player, spectator
  WHERE lobby.id = team.lobby_id AND lobby_player.team_id = team.id AND lobby_player.player_id = ? OR lobby.id = spectator.lobby_id AND spectator.player_id = ?
  ```

---

**The Models**

```
spectator_table = Table('spectator', Base.metadata,
    Column('lobby_id', Integer, ForeignKey('lobby.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('player_id', Integer, ForeignKey('player.steamid'),
        primary_key=True
    ),
)

class Lobby(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'lobby'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('player.steamid'), nullable=False,
        unique=True
    )
    teams = relationship("Team", backref="lobby",
        cascade='save-update,merge,delete'
    )
    spectators = relationship("Player", secondary=spectator_table)

class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'team'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    lobby_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('lobby.id'), nullable=False)
    players = relationship("LobbyPlayer", backref="team",
        cascade='save-update,merge,delete,delete-orphan'
    )

class LobbyPlayer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'lobby_player'
    team_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('team.id'), primary_key=True)
    player_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('player.steamid'), primary_key=True)
    player = relationship("Player", uselist=False)
    cls = Column(Integer)

class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player'
    steamid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

---

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

I'm seeing the same problem you're on SA 0.7.9

What seems to be happing is that the parentheses aren't being applied correctly the way you want them.  I used self_group() which makes this work but the thing is you shouldn't have to use it.  Here are the docs for 
[self_group](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html?highlight=self_group#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.self_group).  I think there should be a better answer then mine, however, this should get you going.

```
query = session.query(Lobby).filter(
    ((Lobby.id == Team.lobby_id) &
    (LobbyPlayer.team_id == Team.id) &
    (LobbyPlayer.player_id == player.steamid)).self_group() |
    ((Lobby.id == spectator_table.c.lobby_id) &
    (spectator_table.c.player_id == player.steamid)).self_group()).all()
```

The generated sql is below, which I believe is what you are after.

```
SELECT lobby.id AS lobby_id, lobby.name AS lobby_name, lobby.owner_id AS lobby_owner_id 
FROM lobby, team, lobby_player, spectator 
WHERE (lobby.id = team.lobby_id AND lobby_player.team_id = team.id AND lobby_player.player_id = ?) OR (lobby.id = spectator.lobby_id AND spectator.player_id = ?)
```

Comment: Yea, I didn't notice the lack of parens, I would have thought the that compound clauses would autogenerate parens.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually it ended up still giving me the incorrect results.

    `SELECT lobby.id AS lobby_id, lobby.name AS lobby_name, lobby.owner_id AS lobby_owner_id
    FROM lobby, team, lobby_player, spectator
    WHERE (lobby.id = team.lobby_id AND lobby_player.team_id = team.id AND lobby_player.player_id = ?) OR (lobby.id = spectator.lobby_id AND spectator.player_id = ?)`

Comment: Do you know what the generated sql you want looks like?

Comment: Hmm, this might also be caused by an issue somewhere else.  I'll keep looking into it and update when I figure it out.

Comment: Came across this while searching for self_group(). The original statement without parens, and the statement in @Tony's answer are equivalent because of operator precedence. In fact, SQLAlchemy will add parens automatically if the logic cannot be expressed otherwise, ex. and_(or_(A, B), and_(C, D), or_(E, F)), where the letters are binary conditions, will translate to (A or B) AND C And D AND (E OR F)

Answer (score 8):

Tony, I never knew about self_group(),  most excellent!

TronPaul,
You can use self_group() to add parens around and ClauseElements, for example:

```
query = session.query(Invoice).join(CustomerQuote).reset_joinpoint()

selections = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
select_ids = Invoice.invoice_id.in_(selections).self_group()
ands = and_(CustomerQuote.customer_id==33,  
       CustomerQuote.invoice_date>=low_date,
       CustomerQuote.invoice_date<=hi_date).self_group()

query = query.filter(or_(select_ors, ands))

SELECT invoice.invoice_id AS invoice_invoice_id, [etc etc....]
FROM invoice INNER JOIN customer_quote ON 
customer_quote.customer_quote_id = invoice.customer_quote_id 
WHERE (invoice.invoice_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)) OR 
      (customer_quote.customer_id = 33 AND 
       invoice.invoice_date >= '2012-01-01' AND 
       invoice.invoice_date <= '2012-12-31')
```

To elaborate on Tony's answer: self_group() is useful for grouping clauses other than "binary" expressions, it works with any ClauseElement.