# OR operator in Flask-sqlachemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I using flask-sqlachemy. It is an extension of sqlachemy and I am not sure how `_or` translates to flask-sqlalchemy. For example, my query:

```
qry = DateModel.query.filter(
            DateModel.from_date >= f_date, 
            DateModel.from_date <= t_date).all()
```

Here two lines inside filter translates to `AND`. So I get all records between `f_date` and `t_date`.

Now I want to add more data with `OR`. For example:

```
qry = DateModel.query.filter(
            DateModel.from_date >= f_date, 
            DateModel.from_date <= t_date 

            OR?

            DateModel.to_date >= f_date, 
            DateModel.to_date <= t_date).all()
```

What would be the syntax for such query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370993/sqlalchemy-query-and-or-issue/13591026) solution with `sqlachemy` is below

```
query = session.query(DateModel).filter(
((DateModel.from_date >= f_date) &
(DateModel.from_date <= t_date)).self_group() |
((DateModel.to_date >= f_date) &
(DateModel.to_date <= t_date)).self_group()).all()
```

Not familiar with `flask-sqlalchemy`, but I'm expecting something like:

```
query = DateModel.query.filter(
((DateModel.from_date >= f_date) &
(DateModel.from_date <= t_date)).self_group() |
((DateModel.to_date >= f_date) &
(DateModel.to_date <= t_date)).self_group()).all()
```